# Given a general sine $g(x) = \sin(b\cdot x+ c)$, when did the last period start prior to $x$.

Tags: trigonometry

This is likely a very dumb question and I should be able to answer it with my knowledge. However, I failed to find a working solution for 2 days now. So please bare with me.

$$g(x) = a\cdot \sin(b\cdot x+ c)$$

I've fitted a general sine function $g(x)$ to data and thus have parameters $b$ and $c$. The question now is: When did the last period of the sine start? (i.e for the lack of better wording: When started it to go up from zero last?)

(i.e. g(x) = 0 is not suffiecient, as only every other zero should be found.)

This is what i have so far: With the duration of one period $t$ beeing $\frac{2\pi}{b}$ I can calculate the phase shift as $\frac{c}{b} \mod t$. The remainder operation is necessary as the result from my function fitting procedure could lead to $c$ shifted by arbitrary number of periods.

With the calculated phase shift I can calculate the desired value as

```
 x[-1] ... <- x koordinate of last data_entry
 x_last = (floor(x[-1] * b)) / b + phase_shift
```

However, when I try to sanity check my result by means of plots I can clearly see this result is wrong. What did I do wrong?

[image: Blue: Data, Calculated X, Orange/Green fitted sine.]

edit: included a parameter $a$ in the sine fomula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function raises from zero every time

$$bx+c=2k\pi.$$

To find the "last" $x$ before some $x_0$,

$$bx+c=2k\pi\le bx_0+c$$
or
$$k\le\frac{bx_0+c}{2\pi}.$$

So

$$k=\left\lfloor\frac{bx_0+c}{2\pi}\right\rfloor.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I can now also see why my approach was faulty to begin with.

Comment: There is one caveat, you could not know. I also fit a parameter $a$ the amplitude of the sine. If it gets fitted to be a negative number the phase is shifted by half a period, which messes with your formula.

Comment: @HaraldThomson: an amplitude must be positive. Convert.